# using SVG sprites in Opera is rendering badly

Tags: css, svg, opera

I would like to use SVG sprites in Opera, and images are shown well on default zoom level, but when i zoom in they are not rendering properly.
The reason i want to use this is so i can have a simple sprite.png fallback for browsers that do not support SVG.
This works well in other browser, only Opera is giving me trouble...
Example of html and css:

```
<span class="members-login sprites">Login</span>


.sprites {
    background: url("/images/sprites.svg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    }
.members-login {
    background-position: 0 -39px;
    display: block;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0 0 0 16px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera is known to cause issues with svg as background images, especialy for sprites. Since you are using fallback png, do that also for opera with opera specific css like this.

```
doesnotexist:-o-prefocus, .sprites {
  background: url('/images/sprites.png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
    }
```

If you find a solution to fix opera issue with svg sprite please post it here.